# setuid does not work with standard user account

Tags: setuid

**Look at this c program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("UID:  %d\n", getuid());
    printf("EUID: %d\n", geteuid());
    system("id");

    printf("res=%d\n", setuid(1001));

    printf("UID:  %d\n", getuid());
    printf("EUID: %d\n", geteuid());
    system("id");
    return 0;
}
```

My user account is "test" (id 1000).
I have a second user account: "test2" (id 1001).

Here is what I've done:

```
gcc test.c -o ./a.out
sudo chown test2 ./a.out
sudo chmod u+s ./a.out
```

Now, here is what happens if I launch ./a.out:

```
UID:  1000
EUID: 1001
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),...
res=0
UID:  1000
EUID: 1001
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),...
```

I do not understand why I do not see uid=1001 in the second part...

I have tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("UID:  %d\n", getuid());
    printf("EUID: %d\n", geteuid());
    system("id");

    printf("res=%d\n", setuid(0));  // <- Here is the change

    printf("UID:  %d\n", getuid());
    printf("EUID: %d\n", geteuid());
    system("id");
    return 0;
}
          
gcc test.c -o ./a.out
sudo chown root ./a.out
sudo chmod u+s ./a.out
```

Here is what I get when running ./a.out:

```
UID:  1000
EUID: 0
uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),...
res=0
UID:  0
EUID: 0
uid=0(root) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),...
```

Now, it works.

So I don't understand why setuid does not work with test2 user and works with root users...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: How secure do you think your system would be if a normal user like `test2` had the privilege to change to a different UID?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things going on here, which cause this confusion. Setuid does work in both cases, it just doesn't work the way you think it would. First, there is the issue of real and effective user IDs. According to the [setuid(2) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)

> If the calling process is privileged (more precisely: if the process
> has the `CAP_SETUID` capability in its user namespace), the real
> UID and saved set-user-ID are also set.

This also means that is the calling process does *not* have the `CAP_SETUID` capability (which is the case of your ordinary users), then the UID will *not* change, only the EUID.

So we move on to the `system()` call. Calling `system("anything")` is the equivalent of calling this:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "anything", (char *) NULL);
```

So it spawns `/bin/sh`, providing arguments so that a new shell will execute your command. I assume you use bash as your shell, because bash works so

> If the  shell  is started  with  the  effective  user (group) id not equal
> to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, (...)
> the effective user id is set to the real user id.

So if your process does not have the `CAP_SETUID` capability, it won't change the real user ID, only the effective UID. Then, when bash is spawned, it drops the effective UID, since UID is not equals to EUID. You can confirm this by calling

```
system("touch /tmp/blah")
```

and adding

```
FILE *file = fopen("/tmp/blah2", "w+");
fclose(file);
```

to your program. You will see that the owner of `/tmp/blah` will be "test" (since the EUID will be dropped on shell execution), but `/tmp/blah2` will belong to "test2".

Comment: A very good answer

Comment: Thanks but there is something I do not understand: "This also means that is the calling process does not have the CAP_SETUID capability (..), then the UID will not change, only the EUID.". For my second test, the calling process do not have CAP_SETUID. But it works...

Comment: But it did have `CAP_SETUID`, since it was a root process. If an executable has the setuid bit set, it runs in the name of the owning user. That is why printing the EUID yielded 0, even before calling `setuid()`. It was effectively a root process from the beginning, and as such, it had `CAP_SETUID`.